# Remove User from Security Group Using JSOM

Tags: 2010, permissions, client-object-model

I'm trying to remove a user from a SharePoint 2010 group using JSOM, but not having much luck.  I've been trying to adapt the script on this page - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/9650/add-and-remove-user-into-sharepoint-group-using-client-objec.aspx

When I run my code, I get an error about line 8 - "Unexpected token =>"  I see other examples with that notation.  What's wrong with it?

```
function removeFromGroup(siteURL) {    
    var client = new ClientContext(siteURL);
    client.ExecuteQuery();
    var website = client.Web;
    client.Load(website, w => w.AllProperties, w => w.SiteGroups, w => w.SiteUserInfoList, w => w.Webs,w => w.Title);
    client.ExecuteQuery();
    var groupCollection = website.SiteGroups;
    client.Load(groupCollection, groups => groups.Include(grps => grps.Users, grps => grps.Title));
    client.ExecuteQuery();
    var user;
    foreach (Group group in groupCollection)
    {
        if (group.Title.Equals("Test"))
        {
            var userInfo = new UserCreationInformation();
            userInfo.LoginName = "<I put the AD username here>";

            user = group.Users.GetByLoginName("<I put the AD username here>");
            group.Users.Remove(user);
            group.Update();
            website.Update();
            client.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is CSOM and doesn't work with JavaScript

Using JavaScript you can do as follows

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var collGroup = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
clientContext.load(collGroup);
clientContext.load(collGroup, 'Include(Users)');

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
    var groupEnumerator = collGroup.getEnumerator();
    while (groupEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oGroup = groupEnumerator.get_current();
        var collUser = oGroup.get_users();
        var userEnumerator = collUser.getEnumerator();
        while (userEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            if(oGroup.get_title() == "Test") {
                var oUser = userEnumerator.get_current();
                if(oUser.get_loginName() == "userlogin") {
                    oGroup.get_users().remove(oUser);
                    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, function (sender, args) {
    alert('Query failed');
});

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('User Removed');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```